# Why do I keep getting 'Predefined type IsExternalInit it not defined' even after upgrading to .net 5?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I removed my `IsExternalInit` definition, as we are now using .net 5.0:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <WarningsAsErrors>nullable</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However I still get this error

> CS0518    Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsExternalInit' is not defined or imported

In files like this

```
public sealed record TestDTO
{
    public string SomePropert{ get; private init; } = default!; // error occurs here
}
```

I can see this is expected behaviour when targeting older frameworks, but shouldn't it work in my case? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild, and clear all temp files bin/obj folders? Are you by chance declaring targetframework multiple times?

Comment: Have you tried the "usual" - delete bin/obj folders, restart VS and rebuild.

Comment: I have cleaned solution, deleted bin/obj in executing project and referenced project, also tried restarting VS and rebuilding

Comment: Any chance you have multiple projects here, and not all of them are targeting *just* .net 5?

Comment: Also: run "dotnet --info" at the command line *in your project folder* - it'll tell you whether the SDK is resolving (and: what version)

Comment: @MarcGravell All of the projects in the solution target .net 5, and when I do `dotnet --info` from the startup project folder it gives me `.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.202`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because one of the projects I reference has a dependency on some library using .net standard

To avoid adding `IsExternalInit.cs` to every project, I just added one to the solution root folder and also added a file called `Directory.Build.Props` with these contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)IsExternalInit.cs" Visible="false" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```